# Why is the sum of counts from df.value_counts() different from the total number of rows of df?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `day_1` in which I want to compute the count for each unique row. I do so by `day_1.value_counts()`. It's very strange that `day_1.shape[0]` is different from `np.sum(day_1.value_counts())`.

Could you please elaborate on this issue?

```
import pandas as pd

# Import dataset
path = r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/BigData/main/2_days.csv'
trends = pd.read_csv(path, header = 0, low_memory = False)

# Subset to a specific day
day_1 = trends[trends.date == '2021-01-01']

# Remove unused columns
columns_to_drop = ['date', 'hour', 'id', 'year', 'month', 'sentence',
                   'offset', 'span', 'value', 'container']
day_1 = day_1.drop(columns = columns_to_drop)

print('The total number of rows is', day_1.shape[0])
print('The total number of rows of all groups is', np.sum(day_1.value_counts()))
```

Comment: `value_counts` doesn't count `NaN`s by default. Can you try with `day_1.value_counts(dropna=False)`?

Comment: NaN values?    Count doesn't 'count' NaNs.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Then it returns `value_counts() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dropna'` :((

Comment: DataFrame.value_counts and Series.value_counts are different. For the DataFrame version, `dropna` doesn't really make sense (or at least is ambiguous as to whether NaN should be considered equal to itself for this) so it's not an argument